# Count number of each char in a String

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, switch-statement

You guys will probably laugh at the way that I implemented this simple task. I know there is a simpler way of doing this but I just really cant think of it right now. Can you guys please help me out?

```
String sample = "hello world";
char arraysample[] = sample.toCharArray();
int length = sample.length();

//count the number of each letter in the string
int acount = 0;
int bcount = 0;
int ccount = 0;
int dcount = 0;
int ecount = 0;
int fcount = 0;
int gcount = 0;
int hcount = 0;
int icount = 0;
int jcount = 0;
int kcount = 0;
int lcount = 0;
int mcount = 0;
int ncount = 0;
int ocount = 0;
int pcount = 0;
int qcount = 0;
int rcount = 0;
int scount = 0;
int tcount = 0;
int ucount = 0;
int vcount = 0;
int wcount = 0;
int xcount = 0;
int ycount = 0;
int zcount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    char c = arraysample[i];
    switch (c) {
        case 'a':
            acount++;
            break;
        case 'b':
            bcount++;
            break;
        case 'c':
            ccount++;
            break;
        case 'd':
            dcount++;
            break;
        case 'e':
            ecount++;
            break;
        case 'f':
            fcount++;
            break;
        case 'g':
            gcount++;
            break;
        case 'h':
            hcount++;
            break;
        case 'i':
            icount++;
            break;
        case 'j':
            jcount++;
            break;
        case 'k':
            kcount++;
            break;
        case 'l':
            lcount++;
            break;
        case 'm':
            mcount++;
            break;
        case 'n':
            ncount++;
            break;
        case 'o':
            ocount++;
            break;
        case 'p':
            pcount++;
            break;
        case 'q':
            qcount++;
            break;
        case 'r':
            rcount++;
            break;
        case 's':
            scount++;
            break;
        case 't':
            tcount++;
            break;
        case 'u':
            ucount++;
            break;
        case 'v':
            vcount++;
            break;
        case 'w':
            wcount++;
            break;
        case 'x':
            xcount++;
            break;
        case 'y':
            ycount++;
            break;
        case 'z':
            zcount++;
            break;
    }
}

System.out.println("There are " + hcount + " h's in here ");
System.out.println("There are " + ocount + " o's in here ");
```

Comment: I believe this is better suited for codereview stackexchange http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: A `Map<Char, Integer>` may prove useful.

Comment: @NappaTheSaiyan ifoyou believe that,you should vote to close this question as off topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for a code review.

Comment: @Raedwald: Not entirely. The question is probably not to review this code but how to work with arrays (a large number of variables). In that sense it's a technical question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an array that uses the ASCII-code:

```
int[] counters = new int[0x100];
for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    char c = string.charAt(i);
    counters[(int) c]++;
}
for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    System.out.println("There are "+counters[(int) c]+" "+c+"'s in the String.");
}
```

What you do is you fetch the right character (as you already did). Now every character has a number. You can look them up here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII. And you increment the associated counter.

Some notes (as a response on Chuck Lowery's comment)

- `0x100` is a hexadecimal number equal to `256` the number of possible characters.
- The datastructure is a simple array. This allows fast access and increment. Although some characters are perhaps not interesting, the memory overhead negligable.

See the [jdoodle](http://jdoodle.com/a/4K).

Comment: Please explain in your answer why you are using `0x100` for the size of your array. Also, explain why you choose this data structure.

Comment: better? [this is some space to post the comment]

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function that would use a regular expression to extract the string containing a concatenation of all the occurences of a given letter given as parameter and return the length of that string.

EDIT: the following page might also prove helpful: [Java: How do I count the number of occurrences of a char in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string)

EDIT #2: Of course the good thing about your approach is that you only loop through the string once.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void countChars(String str) {
    int numOfChars = 'z' - 'a' + 1;
    int[] arr = new int[numOfChars];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        arr[str.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
    }
    System.out.println("There are " + arr['z' - 'a'] + " z's in here ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array where the index corresponds to each character

```
String str = "Hello World";
String strLower = str.toLowerCase();

int[] charCounts = new int[26];

for (int i = 0; i < strLower.length(); i++) {
  char c = strLower.charAt(i);
  int charIndex = (int)c - 97
  charCounts[charIndex]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the 'count' in a single container.  In this case I think a `Map` would be most appropriate.  Using a map you store a piece of information based on a Key : Value pair of any Object.  In this case your Key could be the character (`char` type), like `'a'` or `'z'`, and your Value would be the tally of that character (`int` type).  You can read more about Maps in the Java API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

An example implementation would be

```
Map m = new Map();
m.put('c',11);  //this puts the Value eleven into the map for Key 'c'
m.get('c');   //this would return the value stored for char 'c', in this case 11
```

If you are more comfortable using Arrays, you could store each char value so that the index of 'a' count is [0], the index of 'b' count is [ 1].  Or you could index the array by the ASCII value of each character, try something like `char ch = (int)'a';` which should return 97.

Comment: This will indeed work, although I guess the `HashMap` (`Map` is an interface), will create a large amount of overhead. Furthermore it is even possible that the memory overhead will be larger (as a `HashMap` stores the keys and some kind of `LinkedList` as well).