# Specific digit detector issue

Tags: java, string, digit

I have written a small piece of code where you enter a 3 digit number via the command line, and then it detects how many 5's are in the code.

```
public class fivedet {

     public static void main (String[] args) {
        String input = args[0];
    int[] a = {0,0,0};
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<input.length();i++) {
        a[i] = input.charAt(i) - 48;
    }
    if(a[0]==5) {
        x=5;
    }

    if(a[1]==5) {
        y=5;
    }

    if(a[2]==5) {
        z=5;
    }

    System.out.println("5 digits here:" + x + y + z);
}
}
```

My main question is why I require the -48 term after the input.charAt(i) method in order for each value in a[] to be equal to the actual number I input.

For example I enter 
    java fivedet 505
and without the -48 the array a[]={53,48,53} instead of a[]={5,0,5} and I unfortunately am not experienced enough with coding java (began learning 3 months ago) to understand why this is happening.

I also do want to develop it to be able to detect different digits and for different lengths of input numbers.

I would appreciate any insight as to why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting 48 is a quick but slightly confusing way of converting from a character to an integer. It so happens that the character code for each digit is 48 away from its numeric value.

See this [table of ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/). (Java uses unicode, not ascii - strings are UTF-16 internally -  but the values are valid in this specific case). So the character '0' has the value 48; the character '9' has the value 57.

Another way of doing this would be to take 1-character substrings of `input`, then call `Integer.parseInt()` on that string, converting "1" to 1, "2" to 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to convert to int in order to detect character 5. Just count them as chars.

```
for (char i : args[0].toCharArray()) {
        System.out.print(i == '5' ? i : '0');

    }
```

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string) has good answers to count occurrences of a char in string