# Regex to match 2 or more commas

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to write a regex that will identify whether a string has 2 or more consecutive commas. For example:

```
hello,,457
,,,,,
dog,,,elephant,,,,,
```

Can anyone help on what a valid regex would be?

Comment: [Tools exist all over the net to help you write regex.](http://regex101.com/) It'd be a shame if you didn't use them.

Comment: And it doesn't even require use of regex

Comment: @anubhava is right: you can just as easily call `value.indexOf(",,")` and check to see whether the result is a non-negative number. Using regex does seem overkill in this case. See [indexOf(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) for the details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below regex would matches the strings which has two or more consecutive commas,

```
^.*?,,+.*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hC4iP0/8)

You don't need to include start and the end anchors while using the regex with `matches` method.

```
System.out.println("dog,,,elephant,,,,,".matches(".*?,,+.*"));
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: A greedy match with  `.*,,.*` could work right?. This will ensure at least 2 commas (which the op wants)

Comment: Thank you, this one worked better, I had used matches() to identify if the regex has been found. Thanks for your suggestions everyone

Comment: @user3929182 [accept an answer which helped you the most.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: The engine will actually run this slower using a lazy quantifier,  where `^.*,,.*$` might be quicker. I think there is an optimization caused by `.*` that causes the engine to directly search for constants before it tries anything else. So, possibly it searches for `,,` first.

Answer (score 9):

```
String str ="hello,,,457";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[,]{2,}");
Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(str);
if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("contains 2 or more commas");
}
```

Comment: You can also use `Pattern.matches(".*[,]{2}.*", str)`, this will be shorter. Note that the Pattern class sometimes act like the regex starts with '^' and ends with '$'

Comment: @msrd0 if he uses the pattern you mentioned, then `System.out.println("contains 2 or more commas");` turns into wrong.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Why should it?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
int occurance = StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf("dog,,,elephant,,,,,", ",,");
```

or

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("dog,,,elephant,,,,,", ",,");
```

depend which library you use:
Check the solution here: [Java: How do I count the number of occurrences of a char in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string)

Comment: the op asked for 2 r more ,

Comment: if(count>1) //do something

Comment: I gave the downvote. These methods will count the number of times the comma appears in the entire string, and will not tell you whether or not they appear consecutively. Please edit your answer to meet this requirement.

Comment: I also think the OP wanted to have a regex, so your answer doesn't attempt to answer the question

Comment: Downvote removed. And I don't see anything wrong with providing an alternative to a regular expression. This site would be much less useful if everyone gave the same answer to every question.