# How do I count the number of occurrences of a character in a string?

Tags: java, counter

```
System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
        String userInput= keyb.next();
        char i = userInput.charAt(0); //getting the character by itself
        int counter=0;
        for(int index= 0; index < theString.length(); index++)
        {
            char ch = userInput.charAt(index);
            if (ch==i) //comparing the chosen character to each character in the string
                counter++; //keeping track of how many times you find a match
```

I am brand new to programming and I have to write a program that will count the number of occurrences of a character chosen by the user in a string that is also an input. This is just the part of the program that has the problem, the error I get when running is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1. Not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Post the rest of your code you probably need to change userInput.charAt(index) to theString.charAt(index);

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I count the number of occurrences of a char in a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
        String userInput= keyb.next();
        char i = userInput.charAt(0);//getting the character by itself
        int counter=0;
        for(int index= 0; index< theString.length(); index++)
        {
            char ch = **theString**.charAt(index);
            if (ch==i)//comparing the chosen character to each character in the string
                counter++;//keeping track of how many times you find a match
```

My assumption is that you want to loop through theString comparing each letter of that to the original char. Remove the ** from theString I just added it to draw your attention to the change. I'm guessing theString is defined elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for(int index= 0; index< theString.length(); index++)
```

Where does `theString` come from?  I suspect you mean `userInput`.

Comment: theString is the original string entered at the start of the program. It is what I am trying to count the characters in

Answer (score 1):

### Change To:

```
System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
        String userInput= keyb.next();
        char i = userInput.charAt(0);//getting the character by itself
        int counter=0;
        for(int index= 0; index< userInput.length(); index++)
        {
            char ch = userInput.charAt(index);
            if (ch==i)//comparing the chosen character to each character in the string
                counter++;//keeping track of how many times you find a match
```

you get the out of range because you are not iterating over the user input.

Comment: Alternatively, change to `char ch = theString.charAt(index);`.  I can't tell which is actually wanted.

Comment: this fixed the error but now it won't print the right counter value. It says one no matter the input. ex apples has only one p in it

Answer (score -1):

Check the line number in the stack trace and then debug.

Comment: userinput.charAt(index)->thestring.charAt(index)