# Count a specified number

Tags: java, numbers

I would like to ask you a question, I want to count how many times a specified number is in a given numer (long) from the user and print it as an int.

Could you please help me with this code?

Apologize for my english.

Example:

< number specified = 4; number given = 34434544; result = 5. >

Comment: Convert to String, then read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string

Comment: No need to convert to a String: just test the value with `% 10`, see if it is equal to the 4; then divide value by 10. Repeat until value is zero.

Comment: I'll try it out, thank you all!

Comment: Just a question, how can I somehow test it with a long n and then return it as an int without loosing data?

Comment: Simple: there are a lot fewer than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` digits in both `Long.MIN_VALUE` and `Long.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the least-significant digit is equal to the digit you are searching for; then divide by ten and check again; keep going until you reach zero.

```
int cnt = 0;
while (value != 0) {
  if (value % 10 == digit) ++cnt;
  value /= 10;
}
```

Where you are trying to count the occurrences of `digit` in the big number `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `Scanner` to get input from `System.in`. Then, iterate through the `String` returned by turning it into a `char[]`. Then analyse each `char` and count original characters. Probably use a `Map<Character, Integer>` for this. For each element in the `Map`, iterate by one if it is in the `Map`. Query the `Map` for your desired character and print the result when finished.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CharacterFinder cf = new CharacterFinder();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scan.nextLine();

    Map<Character, Integer> resultsMap = cf.countChar(input);
    System.out.println(resultsMap.get('g'));
}

// Note that 'null' means that it does not appear and if it is null, you ought print 0 instead.
// Also note that this method is case sensitive.
private Map<Character, Integer> countChar(String input) {

    Map<Character, Integer> resultsMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        Character element = input.charAt(i);
        if (resultsMap.containsKey(element)) {
            Integer cCount = resultsMap.get(element);
            resultsMap.put(element, cCount + 1);
        } else {
            resultsMap.put(element, 1);
        }
    }

    return resultsMap;
}
```

Well, unless you already know the `char` you want. In that case, analyse for that exact `char`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CharacterFinder cf = new CharacterFinder();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scan.nextLine();

    // Call counting method and print
    System.out.println(cf.countChar(input, '5'));
}

// Counting method
private int countChar(String input, char c) {
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (input.charAt(i) == c) {
            x++;
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? You mean convert a `long` to a `int`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8:

```
long count = String.valueOf(givenNumber).chars()
        .filter(c -> c == (specifiedNumber + '0'))
        .count();
```

Comment: Thanks you aswell :)