# Count Occurrences of Character in Order

Tags: java

I want to find occurrence of each character in their increasing order.

For eg. for input  `abcddec` output should be  `a1b1c1d1d2e1c2` , but my 
code is giving me output as  `a1b1c2d2e1c2`

what changes I should make?

```
package com.Java8;

public class Occurences {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "abb";
        char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            result = result + arr[i] + count;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate over the string that much, you need only one `for` loop actually. You just need to store the occurrences of the characters you encountered.

Comment: take a look here as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/java-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "abcddecca";
char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Map<Character, Integer> counters = new HashMap<>();
for( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
  Integer count = counters.get( arr[i] );
  if ( count == null ) {
    count = 1;
  } else {
    count++;
  }
  counters.put( arr[i], count );
  sb.append( arr[i] );
  sb.append( count );
}
System.out.println( sb );
```

I would prefer to create some counters state holder and avoid double FOR loop. Also it's not a good practice to use String concatenation in loops,it's better to use StringBuilder.

Comment: Better answer. Avoids the double for plus you used builder :)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the double for. Store the state in a map or something:

```
    String str="abbcece";
    char []charArray=str.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    Map<Character, Integer> occurenceMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for(Character character:charArray){
        Integer occ = 1;
        if(occurenceMap.containsKey(character)){
            occ =  occurenceMap.get(character)+1;
        }
        occurenceMap.put(character, occ);
        result.append(character).append(occ);
    }

    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Comment: just the way I was thinking

Answer (score 0):

Your counting technique counts every time the character appears in the string, not every time the character appears before it in the string + 1. You need to change the `for`loop to something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++){
    int count = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j ++){
        if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
            count ++;           
        }
    }
    result = result + arr[i] + count;
}
```

This will iterate through every character before the character in the `for`loop and check if they are equal

Answer (score 0):

Your inner for loop upper limit should be less than 'i'.

```
public class Occurences {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "abb";
        char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int count = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { //j upper limit should be i
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            result = result + arr[i] + count;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Map** to count the occurrence of each letters:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "abcddec"; 
    Map<Character, Integer> mapCount = new HashMap<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (char c : s.toCharArray()){
        if(mapCount.containsKey(c)){
            mapCount.put(c, mapCount.get(c) +1);
        }
        else mapCount.put(c, 1);
        sb.append(String.valueOf(c) + mapCount.get(c));
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Time complexity of the solution is **O(N)**