# Java loops: Write a program that returns number of occurrences of a string in another string

Tags: java, string, loops, nested-loops

I'm trying to solve this problem but it doesn't seem to work in any way. I tried to search for the problem but all other answers use methods or arrays and we haven't studied them yet so I have to solve the problem with loops only. This is the question:

> Write a program that returns number of occurrences of a string in another string.
>   E.g.
>   Input:
>   First String: the
>   Second String: the students are working hard in the faculty of Engineering because they love it
>   Output:
>   3

this is what I tried:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String s1 = input.nextLine();
    String s2 = input.nextLine();
    int count = 0;

    String text="";

    for(int i = 0; i<s1.length(); i++){
        for(int j =0; j<=s2.length() ; j++){
            if(s1.charAt(i)==s2.charAt(j) && i ==0){
                for(int m=1; m<s1.length();m++){
                    if(s1.charAt(i+1)==s2.charAt(j+1)){
                        if(m==s1.length()){
                            count++;
                        }else{
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);
```

I think I have a problem with the logic. This is what I'm thinking: the program should check the first letter of the first string then check if it checks if it equals the first letter of the second string, then if it doesn't equal it then the program should loop through the second string until it finds a letter that equals the first letter of the first string, if it finds a letter that equals the first string it checks if the second letter of the first string equals the next letter of the other string, if yes then it checks if thats the last letter of the first string if it is then count increases by one, if it isn't it loops the the next characters. I tried to do it a couple of other ways non of my code worked. Can someone help me with the logic?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program? Because that's what you should do.

Comment: @f1sh I don't know how to debug this is my first course taking programming, but I don't get any errors in the code unless I run it, it give index out of bound exception

Comment: Might worth looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/java-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string

Comment: You did it in O(n^2), you can do it O(n)

Comment: @PatrickParker I came across that question but as I mentioned I need to solve it without arrays and the solution provided in that question uses arrays

Comment: @maya91 here's another one that doesn't use arrays http://stackoverflow.com/a/6267655/7098259

Comment: https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java#L6783 and https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/CharSequenceUtils.java#L70

Comment: Thank you for the links but all these use methods and things that I haven't heard of before. The solution should be using nested loops

Answer (score 1):

> the program should check the first letter of the first string then check if it checks if it equals the first letter of the second string,

OK

> then if it doesn't equal it then the program should loop through the second string until it finds a letter that equals the first letter of the first string,

If that's what you want to do, then traversing s2 should be the basis of your outermost loop. But you have written it with traversing s1 as the outermost loop.

> if it finds a letter that equals the first string it checks if the second letter of the first string equals the next letter of the other string, if yes then it checks if thats the last letter of the first string if it is then count increases by one, if it isn't it loops the the next characters.

OK. so you only need one index into s2 (the outer loop), and one index into the potential match with s1 (the inner loop). You don't need another loop beyond that.

A final note, be careful that the sum of your outer loop index (traversing s2) plus the inner index (traversing potential match) does not exceed the bounds of s2. As you have written it now, it can exceed the string lengths, and in fact it does.

```
String s1 = "the";
String s2 = "the students are working hard in the faculty of Engineering because they love it";
int count = 0;
assert(!s1.isEmpty());
int s2LastPositionOfPotentialMatch = s2.length() - s1.length();
for(int i = 0; i < s2LastPositionOfPotentialMatch + 1; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < s1.length(); j++) {
        if(s1.charAt(j) != s2.charAt(i+j)) {
            break;
        } else if(j + 1 == s1.length()) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```