# sort array of characters in the order of occurrence within a string

Tags: java, sorting

If I have an array of characters filled with characters, and I have a `String` initialized with some initial value, then how can I make sure that the characters in the array are sorted in the order of occurents of how they appear within the string.

You can make the following additional assumptions:

- unused characters should appear at the end in their original order.
- if multiple occurrences of the same character occur within the array, they can refer to the same occurrence within the string.

Example, assume following two initialized variables:

```
char [] arr= new char[5] { 'a', 'd', 'v', 'd', 'j' };
String str = "dad";
```

Then the expected result would be that the variable `arr` would have sorted the characters as follows:

```
{ 'd', 'a', 'd', 'v', 'j' }
```

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: try writing some code - or you want us to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "sorting according to the set"?

Comment: For what ultimate goal? What would be the purpose of doing this? Showing your coding attempt may answer these questions but for some reason,  I doubt it.

Comment: yes i want the code i mean that if we have char [ ] arr = new arr[5] and have values {a, d, v, d, j} according to "dad" the sorted array will be {d, a, d, v, j}@ScaryWombat @Maurice Perry

Comment: i just face that problem and i couldn't solve it @DevilsHnd

Comment: [Questions asking for homework](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: An [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6166/167417) for students and those who might answer them

Comment: @mohamedShawky is this a homework?

Comment: @MauricePerry no it's just a question at codefircers

Comment: What would be the expected result if `char[] arr = { 'a', 'd', 'v', 'd', 'j', 'd' }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    char [] arr= { 'a', 'd', 'v', 'd', 'j' };
    String str = "dad";
    int pos = 0;
    for (char c: str.toCharArray()) {
        int i = locate(c, arr, pos);
        if (i >= 0) {
            char x = arr[pos];
            arr[pos] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = x;
            ++pos;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(toString(arr));
}

private static int locate(char c, char[] arr, int start) {
    for (int i = start; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == c) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

UPDATE: the toString method

```
private static String toString(char[] arr) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    buf.append('{');
    boolean first = true;
    for (char c: arr) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        } else {
            buf.append(',');
        }
        buf.append(c);
    }
    buf.append('}');
    return buf.toString();
}
```

UPDATE 2: to preserve the order of the elements that are not in the string.

```
        if (i >= 0) {
            char x = arr[i];
            for (int k = pos; k < i; ++k) {
                char y = arr[k];
                arr[k] = x;
                x = y;
            }
            arr[i] = x;
            ++pos;
        }
```

Comment: Where does the `toString` come from?  Did you mean to use `Arrays.toString()` ?

Comment: Ok, you don't need to do that, `Arrays.toString()` will take care of it.  The solution works, btw.  I would try and find a functional solution with no mutations.  Just out of curiosity.  Thanks.

Comment: If I right understand the requirement of the OP, then your solution is wrong for input `{'a','d','v','x','d','j'}`. The output should be `{d,a,d,v,x,j}` instead of `{d,a,d,x,v,j}`.

Comment: Seems I missed a refresh before. ;-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this solution which (partially) solves the problem.

```
    String source = "pippo";
    Comparator<Character> comparator = new Comparator<Character>() {

        private int countChar(String s, char c) {
            return s.length() - s.replace(Character.toString(c), "").length();
        }
        @Override
        public int compare(Character o1, Character o2) {
            return countChar(source, o2) - countChar(source, o1);
        }
    };
    Character[] charObjectArray = source.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c).toArray(Character[]::new);
    Arrays.sort(charObjectArray , comparator);
```

What is still missing is the implementation of this feature:

> if multiple occurrences of the same character occur within the array,
>   they can refer to the same occurrence within the string.

The method to count occurrences of char in a String was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8910767/379173