# Check schema of a record in java

Tags: java, regex, tokenize

I have a text file.  Each line in the file represents a record having 'n' number of columns delimited by a | (pipe) character. The column-values are of type int, string, date, timestamp, etc. Empty string and spaces are also possible as column values.

I am validating only the count of the column-values and validation of data type is not required.

Sample valid records of 5 columns each:

```
1234|xyz|abc|2016-04-08 11:12:40|234
1235|efgh|abc|2016-04-09 11:25:40|
1236|efghij| ||
```

Validation code:

```
boolean valid = true;
String line = buffReader.readLine();
String[] tokens = null;
while (line != null){
    tokens = line.split("\\|");
    if ((tokens.length==4 || tokens.length==5) && countPipes(line)==4){

    } else {
        valid = false;
        break;
    }
    line = buffReader.readLine();
}

private int countPipes(String line){
    int count = 0;
    count = line.length() - line.replace("|", "").length();
    return count;
}
```

I feel that the code can be better.
Can someone let know how i can improve this code?

Comment: Are you allowing for escaped `|` in the column values? If yes, your validation needs to handle this.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks for pointing out the bug. I have corrected it.

Comment: @dpr The column values will not have "|" for sure.

Comment: So now you have a `countPipes` method? You should [edit] the question and add that. If it counts pipes, there is no reason to actually split the line at all.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Added the countPipes method too.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Added the logic. Courtesy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/java-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can simply check that there are four pipes in the line. If there are exactly four pipes, then there are five columns, which may be empty (which you allow).

```
while (line != null) {
    if ( countPipes(line) != 4 ) {
        valid = false;
        break;
    }
    line = buffReader.readLine();
}
```

Now you don't need to split the line at all.

A note about splitting, though. If you use the `split` with two parameters, and use a negative number, the split will contain entries for the empty elements as well. Here is a demonstration:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String line = "A|B|||";

        String[] zeroSplit = line.split("\\|");
        String[] negativeSplit = line.split("\\|",-1);

        System.out.println( "When split without parameter: " + zeroSplit.length );
        System.out.println( "When split with negative parameter: " + negativeSplit.length );
    }
}
```

The output here is:

```
When split without parameter: 2
When split with negative parameter: 5
```

So in this case, you can check that your split is exactly of length 5, and get the same result.

```
while (line != null) {
    if ( line.split("\\|",-1).length != 5 ) {
        valid = false;
        break;
    }
    line = buffReader.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all and most important: You got a serious error in your if statement, as you are using a single `=` (assignment operator) instead of the comparison operator `==`!!

Regarding code cleanup: It's only a slight adjustment and there are probably better ways to validate this but it's the first thing that came into my mind:

```
boolean valid = true;
String line = buffReader.readLine();
while (valid && (line != null)){
    String[] tokens = line.split("\\|");
    valid = !(tokens.length == 4 || tokens.length == 5);
    line = buffReader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the equality flaw.  I have corrected it.