# find how many numberof times a character from a String is repeated in java

Tags: java, string

I have a String of say, length is 5000. I want to find out the number of times the letter 'R' (Case Sensitive) is used. Below are the two passable solution...

1. Convert to char array, loop it to perform a condition to check and increment a counter.
2. Use Substring() with the character 'R' to get an array which could fetch a array. So, the total length of the array +1 will be number of times, the 'R' character in the string(This is not a better solution)

Help me out with the efficient solution on the cards for this. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the first solution?

Comment: loop the String then test if it is `R` using the setCharAt(i) method of the String class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/java-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string --refer link should provide plenty of ways

Comment: @kayaman... need an effective way other than that.

Comment: @nandula thanks... Will check out!

Answer (score 6):

try this one

```
String text = "ABCabcRRRRRrrr";
int count = text.length() - text.replace("R", "").length();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using java >= 8 you can use the Streams:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str= "abcderfgtretRetRotpabcderfgtretRetRotp"
    System.out.println(str.chars().filter(c -> c == 'R').count());
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks! Need to investigate on the internal logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = //the actual string
for(int i=0;i<str.length();++i)
{
    if(str.charAt(i)=='R')
    {
        capitalRCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is traditional way to check... any other trendy way with minimal processing time??

Comment: @VijayLMarcelin well I prepare logic because it exercise your mind plus when you know logic you can just do it with your logic instead of using many classes to adapt to..

Comment: Logics are always welcome... is there any api specific to resolve it further with quicker processing time.