# Regex to identify strings containing a particular symbol?

Tags: java, regex

I have set of inputs ++++,----,+-+-.Out of these inputs I want the string containing only + symbols.

Comment: `^[^+]*\+[^+]*$`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I want an example.

Comment: Please format your question and add counter examples since it's actually not clear at all. Also, show what you have already tried.

Comment: @user3761068: what do you mean with an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How do I count the number of occurrences of a char in a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/java-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see if a String contains nothing but `+` characters, write a loop to check it:

```
private static boolean containsOnly(String input, char ch) {
    if (input.isEmpty())
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        if (input.charAt(i) != ch)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Then call it to check:

```
System.out.println(containsOnly("++++", '+')); // prints: true
System.out.println(containsOnly("----", '+')); // prints: false
System.out.println(containsOnly("+-+-", '+')); // prints: false
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you must do it using regex (worse performance), then you can do any of these:

```
// escape special character '+'
input.matches("\\++")

// '+' not special in a character class
input.matches("[+]+")

// if "+" is dynamic value at runtime, use quote() to escape for you,
// then use a repeating non-capturing group around that
input.matches("(?:" + Pattern.quote("+") + ")+")
```

Replace final `+` with `*` in each of these, if an empty string should return `true`.

Comment: Yup. I'm always keen to upvote a non-regex solution.

Comment: Is there any regular expression for this.

Comment: Yes, my answer has it.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression for checking if a string is composed of only one repeated symbol is

`^(.)\1*$`

If you only want lines composed by '+', then it's

`^\++$`, or `^++*$` if your regex implementation does not support `+`(meaning "one or more").

Comment: Yup, that's the one.

Comment: Nope it's not. That doesn't check for a *particular* symbol, like `+`. It checks if all chars are the same. --- Also, it's a duplicate of [answer by Bathsheba](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43300131/5221149).

Comment: @Andreas, yes, it checks if **all** the chars are the same. No, it's not a duplicate of Bathsheba's answer.

Comment: @MauroLacy Ok, you changed `+` (1 or more) to `*` (0 or more). Other than that it's a duplicate, since `^` and `$` are unnecessary when using `matches()`.

Comment: @Andreas. So? The answer is therefore more general, and therefore, correct. That is **the** regex to check for that, independently of calling conventions. And, addressing the first part of your comment, a string of only one char is composed of all the same chars, you know?

Comment: Yes, and you regex will match a string of *any* one char, but OP only wants to match string consisting of nothing but `+` characters. *"I have set of inputs `++++`, `----`, `+-+-`. Out of these inputs I want the string containing only `+` symbols."* So, only the first one. You match the second one too.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that now you are misunderstanding OP's question.

Comment: I agree, *you* are misunderstanding the question. *"I want the string containing only `+` symbols"* is pretty clear. OP doesn't want a string containing only `-` symbols, or any other symbols.

Answer (score 0):

For a sequence of the same symbol, use

`(.)\1+`

as the regular expression. For example, this will match `+++`, and `---` but not `+--`.

Comment: Not sure that it is what s?he's looking for, it's actually unclear. See the example `+-+-+-+-` added in the question.

Comment: But I want to check only +++ not ---

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I actually find question quite unclear. `+-+-+-+-` does not *"contains only one particular symbol"*, it contains 2.

Comment: I read the question to mean a string of arbitrary length but containing only one distinct character.

Comment: @user3761068: it is more clear, but are always missing: 1) what you have already tried (SO isn't a code writing service), 2) a well formatted question.

Comment: [Answer by MauroLacy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43300252/5221149) fixed a bug in your regex, since your regex requires 2 or more characters to match.

Answer (score 0):

Regex pattern: `^[^\+]*?\+[^\+]*$`

This will only permit one plus sign per string.

[Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/sEUoGd/1)

Explanation:

```
^         #From start of string
[^\+]*    #Match 0 or more non plus characters
\+        #Match 1 plus character
[^\+]*    #Match 0 or more non plus characters
$         #End of string
```

edit, I just read the comments under the question, I didn't actually steal the commented regex (it just happens to be intellectual convergence):

Whoops, when using matches disregard ^ and $ anchors.

```
input.matches("[^\\+]*?\+[^\\+]*")
```