# Programmatically center text output in for loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to put out the following pattern of chars:

```
    x
   xxx
  xxxxx
 xxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
```

And this is what I currently have:

```
String y = "";
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
      y="";
      for(int s = 0; s < i; s++)
      {
         y+= "x";
      }
      System.out.println(y);
}
```

This outputs

```
x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
xxxxxx
xxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
```

Which is an approach. I'm well aware of the fact that the target pattern increments two `x` each execution of the loop, and I know that I have to use blank spaces and insert them. However, I'm stuck with this really simple task.

EDIT: The task is to only use two loops. I thought of a way using three, though, but couldn't straight forwardly figure out a way to use two loops.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, 10).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
    .mapToObj(i -> Stream.generate(() -> "").limit((lines - i) / 2).collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
      + Stream.generate(() -> "x").limit(1 + i).collect(Collectors.joining()))
    .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);`

Comment: Thank you,  @JoeC! However, it's not an actual homework but something I stumbled upon while checking some pivotal algorithms and functions (despite being an ordinary programmer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are many different possible answers to this question, this is just one possible solution.

For this solution, I don't bother printing the spaces after the X's. I only print those that come before.

```
int baseWidth = 10;


for (int a = baseWidth ; a > 0 ; a--) {
  for (int b = 0 ; b < a - 1 ; b++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
  }

  for (int b = a - 1 ; b < baseWidth - (a - 1) ; b++) {
    System.out.print("X");
  }

  System.out.print("\n");
}
```

The result of the above code is as follows for baseWidth = 10:

```
    XX
   XXXX
  XXXXXX
 XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
```

The result of the above code is as follows for baseWidth = 9:

```
    X
   XXX
  XXXXX
 XXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
```

---

Following the edit of your post, this next code snip performs the same function as the previous one, but with only two loops.

```
int baseWidth = 9;


for (int a = baseWidth ; a > 0 ; a--) {
  for (int b = 0 ; b < baseWidth - (a - 1) ; b++) {
    if (b < a - 1) {
      System.out.print(" ");
    }

    if (b >= a - 1 && b < baseWidth - (a - 1)) {
        System.out.print("X");
    }
  }

  System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using two `for` loops, I used 1 `for` loop and 1 `if` statement (which is not a loop).

```
    String spaces = "     ";
    String word = "";
    String X = "x";
    for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
        if (i%2 == 0) {
         word = spaces + X;  
         System.out.println(word);
         spaces = spaces.replaceFirst(" ","");
         X += "xx";
        }
    }
```

and the output is how you asked:

```
     x
    xxx
   xxxxx
  xxxxxxx
 xxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem, with just one loop, you can use `padLeft` with `String.format`, here is a simple example :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int n = 5;
    String str;
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        str = String.format("%0" + ((n - i) * 2 + 1) + "d", 0).replace("0", "x");
        System.out.println(String.format("%1$" + ((i - 1 + str.length())) + "s", str));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
    x
   xxx
  xxxxx
 xxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Great approach, however, I was given the task to only use TWO for loops (I edited the question just before after I noticed I had forgotten this point). Is this technically even possible? I made a similar approach with more than two loops, though.

Comment: so you want to use just two loops @John ?

Comment: @John check my edit, you can solve your problem with just one loop ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, let's have a no-loops-at-all solution too:

```
static Stack<String> getStarryStrings (String lastString, Stack<String> result) {
    //First count the number of *'s in the string
    //From:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/java-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string
    int starCount = lastString.length() - lastString.replace("*", "").length();
    if(starCount<1) return result;
    result.push(lastString);

    //Find first and last occurrences of *
    int fio = lastString.indexOf('*');
    int lio = lastString.lastIndexOf('*');

    //And replace them with white spaces
    StringBuilder nextLast = new StringBuilder(lastString);
    nextLast.replace(fio,fio+1," ");
    nextLast.replace(lio, lio + 1, " ");

    //And recurse...
    return getStarryStrings(nextLast.toString(),result);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<String> res = getStarryStrings("*********",new Stack<>());
    while(!res.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(res.pop());
    }
```

Displays:

```
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********
```

**Note:**
I am certain this can be done in a more efficient way to eliminate the need for a `java.util.Stack`. My only criteria was not using loops. I am letting the stack to remain there to show the recursive nature of the solution. It can easily be improved to use a `StringBuilder` in place of a stack.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain two pointer `l` & `r` which will decide from which position to which you have to print `*` otherwise print space. After each line decrease the `l` and increase `r` by 1, as triangle grows 1 step to left and right in each line.

Using only two loops...

```
int n = 5; // number of lines...
int l = n-1, r = n-1;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int s = 0; s < 2*n; s++) {
        if(s >= l && s<= r)
            System.out.print("*");
        else
            System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    l--; r++;
}
```

Output:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Answer (score 0):

Two Loops.

```
char[] s = "           ".toCharArray();
int start = 5;
int end = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = start; j <= end; j++) {
        s[j] = 'x';

    }       
    start--;
    end++;
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

One loop

```
char[] s = "           ".toCharArray();
int start = 4;
int end = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Arrays.fill(s, start, end, 'x');//Remembering importing Arrays class
    start--;
    end++;
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: If you have any doubt with the code just reply here in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at this:

```
public class CenterText {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        centerText(10, 'X');
    }

    public static void centerText(int noOfLines, char theChar){

        final int totalNoOfChars = noOfLines * 2;
        String totalSpaces = "";
        String chars = "";

        for (int i=0; i<totalNoOfChars; i++){
            totalSpaces += " ";
        }

        for (int j=1 ; j<=totalNoOfChars; j++){
            chars+=theChar;
            if(j%2==0){
                System.out.println(totalSpaces.substring(0, noOfLines-(j/2)) + chars);
            }       
        }   
  }


}
```

### Examples:

Input:

```
centerText(10, 'X');
```

Output:

```
         XX
        XXXX
       XXXXXX
      XXXXXXXX
     XXXXXXXXXX
    XXXXXXXXXXXX
   XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Input:

```
centerText(7, '#');
```

Output:

```
      ##
     ####
    ######
   ########
  ##########
 ############
##############
```