# how to print christmas tree for n in java

Tags: java, tree

```
public class tree {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n ;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input value n:");
    n = input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i=i+2) {
        for (int j = n/2; j==0; j--)
            System.out.print(" ");
        for (int k = 0; k <=i ; k++) 
            System.out.print("#");
             System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This is what requires in task:

[image]

What do i need to repair?
And how to Print perform in function that is called from the main program?

Comment: @Milan Please have a look at this question as well, I believe that is exactly what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668323/programmatically-center-text-output-in-for-loop/43669102#43669102

Comment: For starters, you need to replace `"*"` with `"#"`. Then you need to fix the `j` loop, because it always prints the same number of spaces. Don't you think the value of `i` would be needed to determine the number of spaces to print?

Comment: Sorry, first time using stackoverflow, the number n represents
number of # in last row .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your code prints `*` characters, but should print `#` characters, and that there should be single spaces between the `#` characters.

```
 Wrong            Correct
   *                 #
  ***              # # #
 *****           # # # # #
*******        # # # # # # #
```

So, for the fun of it, here is an non-traditional way to do it the correct way for any size tree:

```
private static void printChristmasTree(int n) {
    final int w = n * 2 - 1;
    char[] buf = new char[w * 3 - 2];
    Arrays.fill(buf, ' ');
    for (int i = w - 1; i < buf.length; i += 2)
        buf[i] = '#';
    for (int s = 0; s < w; s += 2)
        System.out.println(new String(buf, s, s + w));
}
```

Output from `printChristmasTree(6)`:

```
          #
        # # #
      # # # # #
    # # # # # # #
  # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # #
```

---

Anyway, back to your code. Your output for `n = 6` is:

```
*
***
*****
```

Your outer `for` loop uses `i=i+2`<sup>1</sup>, which means you only get half the number of rows you need. Either change to `i++`, or change condition to `i < n * 2`. Let's go with second option, even though that would only make sense if you intended to print spaces between stars.
  <sub>1) Better written as `i += 2`</sub>

That changes output to:

```
*
***
*****
*******
*********
***********
```

Now the number of rows is correct, and the number of stars on each row is correct. Let's look at your space indenting loop.

Since `j = n/2 = 3`, the condition `j==0` is immediately false, and that is why you don't get any spaces.

Perhaps you meant `j != 0`, but the problem is that the loop doesn't use the `i` value, so that would always print 3 spaces. We can fix that by starting the loop with `j = n - i / 2 - 1`.

**Fixed code:**

```
private static void printChristmasTree(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n * 2; i += 2) {
        for (int j = n - i / 2 - 1; j > 0; j--)
            System.out.print(" ");
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) 
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
```

If we had chosen the first option earlier, i.e. change to `i++`, the code would be (with some other slight changes):

```
private static void printChristmasTree(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = n - 1; j > i; j--)
            System.out.print(' ');
        for (int j = i * 2; j >= 0; j--) 
            System.out.print('*');
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Number of rows must be limited to when *=n , so if n=11 the result will be: *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********

Comment: and if n=7 : *
    ***
   *****
  *******

Comment: @MilanMilosevic So `n` is the *width*, not the *height* (number of rows)? Perhaps that should have been clarified in the question. It also makes it more error-prone, i.e. what does `n = 6` mean? Having `n` be the height makes a lot more sense, but that never stopped a bad assignment.