# How to create unigram in java ? each 'char' have 'int' to count how many 'char' in txt file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, n-gram

I have trouble reading the `char` part of a text file and making each `char` have a value that is the number of that `char` in the file.

For example:

> i'm eating

should be:

```
i = 2
m = 1
e = 1
a = 1
t = 1
n = 1
g = 1
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `Map<Character, Integer`> ? or a simple `int[]` if you have a specific set of character (letters only for example could be done with (int[26]). Now try this and come back to us with something you tried. Can't say more than this.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Show us some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/java-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java char type is a 16-bit integer (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), so a relatively small array can store the counters:

```
int statistics[]=new int[65536];
int onechar;
while(-1!=(onechar=br.read())){
    statistics[onechar]++;
}

for(int i=' ';i<statistics.length;i++){
    if(statistics[i]>0){
        System.out.println(String.format("%c: %d",i,statistics[i]));
    }
}
```

Where `br` is the `BufferedReader`