# how to count many times a character occurs in a string without using s loop

Tags: java

the code below is meant to count each time character 'x' occurs in a string but it only counts once ..

I do not want to use a loop.

```
public class recursionJava

{

   public static void main(String args[])

   {

      String names = "xxhixx";

      int result = number(names);
      System.out.println("number of x: " + result);
   }

   public static int number (String name)
   {

      int index = 0, result = 0;

      if(name.charAt(index) == 'x')
      {
         result++;
      }
      else
      {
         result = result;
      }
            index++;

      if (name.trim().length() != 0)
      {
        number(name);
      }
      return result;
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `result = result;`?

Comment: "I do not want to use a loop" = "I must use recursion because the homework says so"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How do I count the number of occurrences of a char in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/java-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string)

Comment: its not a duplicate they are totally different

Comment: @kayaman its not a homework its a study set

Answer (score 6):

You could do a replacement/removal of the character and then compare the length of the resulting string:

```
String names = "xxhixx";
int numX = names.length() - names.replace("x", "").length(); // numX == 4
```

Comment: Is this really more efficient (and idiomatic) than cycling through the string?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Because it answers the question,

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca It is common knowledge that regex type solutions, while elegant, can perform poorly as compared to direct base string operations.  So this may not be the most performant solution.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca It's obvious using simple loop gives the best performance, and OP requests not to do this.

Comment: In a similar vain: `names.replaceAll("[^x]", "").length()`. Alternatively, `names.split("x", -1).length()-1`.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use a loop, you can use recursion:

```
public static int number (String name)
{
    if (name.length () == 0)
        return 0;
    int count = name.charAt(0)=='x' ? 1 : 0;
    return count + number(name.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Interesting that people aren't piling on this question complaining about its (lack of) efficiency ([vs this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49106335/3788176)).

Comment: I didn't say it was: I'm just pointing out that there is a chain of comments on the other answer complaining that isn't efficient, but not here.

Comment: I'm not criticizing either answer.

Answer (score 4):

As of Java 8 you can use streams:

```
"xxhixx".chars().filter(c -> ((char)c)=='x').count()
```

Answer (score 4):

Previous recursive answer (from Eran) is correct, although it has quadratic complexity in new java versions (substring copies string internally). It can be linear one:

```
    public static int number(String names, int position) {
    if (position >= names.length()) {
        return 0;
    }

    int count = number(names, position + 1);

    if ('x' == names.charAt(position)) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work because of two things:

1. Every time you're calling your recursive method `number()`, you're setting your variables `index` and `result` back to zero. So, the program will always be stuck on the first letter and also reset the record of the number of x's it has found so far.
2. Also, `name.trim()` is pretty much useless here, because this method only removes whitespace characters such as space, tab etc.

You can solve both of these problems by

1. making `index` and `result` global variables and
2. using `index` to check whether or not you have reached the end of the String.

So in the end, a slightly modified (and working) Version of your code would look like this:

```
public class recursionJava {

    private static int index = 0;
    private static int result = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String names = "xxhixx";

        int result = number(names);
        System.out.println("number of x: " + result);
    }

    public static int number (String name){
        if(name.charAt(index) == 'x')
            result++;

        index++;

        if(name.length() - index > 0)
            number(name);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StringUtils.countMatches`

StringUtils.countMatches(name, "x");

Comment: That uses a loop internally.

Comment: @Kayaman So does the String method `replace` used in the current highest voted answer.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS that's true, but you're not really putting them on the same line are you.

Comment: I think recursion is an interesting solution and I would recommend to use this approach during a job interview etc. , but for a real life project the StringUtils class provides simpler and cleaner usage.

Comment: I suppose you are referring to [Appache Commons `StringUtils.countMatches`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#countMatches-java.lang.CharSequence-char-) - might be worth mentioning that.