# How to check specific character occurred only once in java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have alphanumeric string where the only  `#.-` are the allowed special characters

my current regex is `^[a-zA-Z0-9][-#._ a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$`

which is accepting string as `Exam1,Exam#1,Exam1.1`
but is also accepting `Exam ##1,Exam 1..1`

How can I make it match special character only once

Comment: Why don't you just count the number of occurrences?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How do I count the number of occurrences of a char in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/java-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string)

Comment: If you do not want repeating special character allowed, what about this case? For example, `Exam #.1 Exam 1.#1 Exam 1.-1` Is this case all right?

Answer (score 0):

First let me explain you regex

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][-#._ a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$
```

Start with character `a-z or A-Z or 0-9` followed by atleast one or more of the followed characters.

So move the special character `[-#.]` into seperate character class and surrounded it with other characters `[-#._ a-zA-Z0-9 ]`

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][_a-zA-Z0-9 ]+[-#.]?[_a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you talk mean that their can be only one group of special caracters, the following statement should do the trick:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*[-#.]*[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*`

I'll break it down:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]` means it must start with one alphanumeric character

`[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*` means there might be following alphanumeric characters

`[-#.]*` means somewhere in the string, there can be a sequence of special characters

`[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*` means string might end with a sequence of alphanumeric characters or special characters

The first and second part are close but different to prevent a space to be placed at the beginning.

The fact of wrapping the special characters sequence the same structure with  `*` allows it to be anywhere.

Some [references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)