# LeanFT to verify specific text is present

Tags: java, leanft

I need to verify that a specific string of text is present on webpage and check the number of occurences in LeanFT. I have tried code below to verify if text is present:

```
browser = BrowserFactory.launch(BrowserType.CHROME);
browser.getVisibleText().contains("Success");
```

Comment: You say you tried this but not what the result was, what problem are you facing?

Comment: @Motti : Output of `getVisibleText()` method doesn't contain word "Success", but it is present on page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `getVisibleText` on `Browser` is the best fit for the problem you're facing. AFAIK `getVisibleText` uses OCR and not the application's underlying technology.

A better way, I think, would be to identify the `Web.Element` that contains *"Success"*. If you don't want to bother getting the specific element you can use the `Page`'s `text` property.

I'm not familiar with LeanFT's Java SDK but in JavaScript it would be written like this:

```
expect(browser.$(Web.Page({})).text()).toContain("Success");
```

**Edit:** according to comments (thanks [@Adelin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3233388/adelin)), the Java equivalent is:

```
browser.getPage().getText().contains("Success");
```

Comment: on Java SDK you need to get the page `browser.getPage()` on which you can call `getInnerText()`. To sum up: `browser.getPage().getInnerText().contains("Success");`

Comment: indeed `getVisibleText` uses OCR, which means that **(1)** will only work in windows OS **(2)** it might return `5uccess` because that's what OCR may have recognized. So yeah, better use `innerText` directly

Comment: @Adelin : Is it possible to get back number of occurences too?

Comment: @plaidshirt as `getInnerText` returns a string, same rules apply, so you could use [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/java-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string)

Comment: @Adelin: `getPage()` doesn't have `getInnerText()` method, cannot resolve it.

Comment: Indeed looks like it's called  [`getText()`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/JavaSDKReference/index.html). Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: @Motti : I tried it, text is present on page, but it can't found it. I tried `browser.getPage().getText()` too, but output seems empty. I assume, it should give all the text from page.

Comment: @plaidshirt, does the page contain frames? If so you need to get text from the relevant frame.