# count occurrence of a character in a given string using one for loop with java

Tags: java, for-loop

This is the reference code:

```
    // Create an array of size 256 i.e. ASCII_SIZE
    int count[] = new int[MAX_CHAR];

    int len = str.length();

    // Initialize count array index
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        count[str.charAt(i)]++;

    // Create an array of given String size
    char ch[] = new char[str.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        ch[i] = str.charAt(i);
        int find = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {

            // If any matches found
            if (str.charAt(i) == ch[j])
                find++;
        }

        if (find == 1)
            System.out.println("Number of Occurrence of " +
                    str.charAt(i) + " is:" + count[str.charAt(i)]);
    }
```

The output is supposed to resemble:

> Number of occurrence of 'x' is: 'times it occured'

If the letter has occurred previously then only display the occurrence once.

---

I get the logic using 2 for loops, although my teacher said its possible to execute this application using only 1 for loop.

the issue i'm running into is:
I'm able to find if the character has been already found only if they are beside each other. 


How are you expected to check if all the previous character have been found without another for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/java-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Are you finding the occurrence of a specific characters or for all characters in that string?

Comment: finding all the characters in the string

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` (Key: Character, Value: Character count) to store your character count.

You only need to loop over your characters once:

```
String input = "this is input string";
Map<Integer, Integer> charCount = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int c : input.toCharArray()) {
    if (!charCount.containsKey(c)) {
       charCount.put(c, 1);
    } else {
       charCount.put(c, charCount.get(c) + 1);
    }
}

// Here you print the char count:
for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : charCount.entrySet()) {
    // (char) entry.getKey() is the character
    // entry.getValue() is number of occurence
}
```

Without `Map`:

```
int[][] count = new int[MAX_CHAR][2];
for (int c : input.toCharArray()) {
    count[c][0] += 1; // Increase occurrence by 1
    count[c][1] = 1; // Mark this character exists in string
}
// Here you can print the count of char per character
// Not that, you can use count[c][1] to determine that if the character exists in your String
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++) {
    if (count[i][1] == 1) {
        System.out.println("Char: " + (char) i + " Occurence: " + count[i][0]);
    }
}
```

**Edit**
As @oreh suggest, we don't even need a two dimension arrays:

```
int[] count = new int[MAX_CHAR];
for (int c : input.toCharArray()) {
    count[c][0] += 1; // Increase occurrence by 1
}
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CHAR; i++) {
    if (count[i] > 0) {
        System.out.println("Char: " + (char) i + " Occurence: " + count[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but the teacher said that its possible without using maps.

Comment: Yes ofcourse. Use your array like your idea. Do the exact loop as me but use array to back it

Comment: Using Map is overhead for 26 letters.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik `// Create an array of size 256 i.e. ASCII_SIZE`  I don't think it's limited by 26 chars

Comment: Yes but according to description, I can see that he searches for letters only.

Comment: `charCount.put(c, charCount.get(c) + 1);` a while ago I see similar question and there was an advise to use `merge()` against `put()` and even better `AtomicInteger` to not produce new instances of `Integer`

Comment: If you read the document about [`merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) you will see it introduce unnecessary code in this case and the core implementation is just the same. It's just a syntax sugar

Comment: The issue i'm having with this code now is that it prints every occurrence, even if its >1

Comment: Are you using the version without Map? My code without `Map` runs fine

Comment: Think the second approach can be implemented with one-dimentional array. While printing use this condition `count[i] > 0`

Comment: thx for the link on merge method. I actually didn't check the doc

Comment: Updated answer, cheer! :)

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to find e.g only letters, then you know the range of ASCII codes. In this case, it is enough to use 1D array and represend an index as symbol code with offset. E.g. to find only letters, you are able to create array `int[] count = new int[26]`, and `int total_a = count[0]; // or count['a' - 'a']` contains counter for `a`, and for leter `z` we have last index: `int total_z = count[25]; // or count['z' - 'a']`:

```
public static void printLetterOccurrence(String str) {
    int[] count = new int['z' - 'a' + 1];
    str = str.toLowerCase();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        if (str.charAt(i) >= 'a' && str.charAt(i) <= 'z')
            count[str.charAt(i) - 'a']++;

    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)
        if (count[i] > 0)
            System.out.println("Number of Occurrence of " + (char)('a' + i) + " is: " + count[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static char getMax(String text) {
    int MAX_CHARS = 256;
    int curr_max = -1;
    char curr_max_char = '-';
    
    int count[] = new int[MAX_CHARS];
    int len = text.length();
    
    for(int i =0; i<len; i++ ) {
        count[text.charAt(i)]++;
        
        if(count[text.charAt(i)] > curr_max) {
            curr_max = count[text.charAt(i)]++;
            curr_max_char = text.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    
    return curr_max_char;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).