# Number of times the last character appears in JAVA only use String

Tags: java, string

I'm doing a part of a program, where I should see the number of times the last character appears in JAVA.

The problem is that I am new with the use of Strings ( and only can use String ). Informing a bit I have seen that with equals I can compare Strings. And with substring I can select each of the letters one by one in a loop. The problem comes when I compile, that I go out of the index of the String. And I do not understand why, since I only get to .length - 1

```
    String aux;
    int cont = 0;

    aux = cadena.substring(cadena.length()-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length()-1; i++) {
        if(cadena.substring(i,1).equals(aux)) {
            cont++;
        }
    }
```

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:-1

In this line

> if(cadena.substring(i,1).equals(aux))

Comment: use `charAt` instead of `substring` and make `aux` a `char`, if that's permitted. Or, even better, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8910767/133203) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have done is like `"Hello".substring(3, 1)`

`substring` method takes two arguments `startIndex` and `endIndex`. so end index should always be greater than start index.

In `cadena.substring(i,1)`, the value of `i` will go from `0` to `cadena.length()-2`, because of condition `i<cadena.length()-1`

Comment: Thanks to your answer. I found my error. You say me "startIndex and endIndex" then i think that i can change "cadena.substring(i,1)" for > "cadena.substring(i,i+1)" . Then im taking only the next one. Right? And i change too "i < cadena.length()-1"  for > "i < cadena.length()"

Comment: you can use charAt(i) method in string,  that will be more convenient when you are deling with characters

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
int count = 0;

char lastChar = cadena.charAt(cadena.length()-1);

for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length()-1; i++) {
   if(lastChar==cadena.charAt(i)) count++;
}
```