# How to improve this function that returns a boolean if there is same amount of x and o's

Tags: java

im trying to do this probelm "Check to see if a string has the same amount of 'x's and 'o's. The method must return a boolean and be case insensitive. The string can contain any char."

However i am failing a few tests so i am wondering is there a better way of doing this?

```java
public class XO {

  public static boolean getXO (String str) {
  boolean Boolean = false;
    String[] x = str.split("x");
    String[] o = str.split("o");
    // Good Luck!!
    if(x.length == o.length){
    Boolean = true;
    }
    return Boolean;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please carefully read the Javadoc for `String#split()`. It does not do what you appear to think it does.

Comment: @JimGarrison to be fair, this probably still works, because you basically get (number of x's) + 1

Comment: Calling a variable `Boolean` is not a very good idea.

Comment: @JClassic it doesn't. What about, say, `oooxxx`?

Comment: Having a variable is a bad idea. You can just return true directly.

Comment: @AndyTurner you're right

Comment: This approach would probably work for you: `int xCount = Math.abs(str.replace("x", "").length() - str.length());`

Answer (score 2):

Your method does not appear to be case insensitive; I would loop over all of the letters in the input `String` (after first converting it to lower case) and count the `x` and `o` characters. Something like,

```
int x = 0, o = 0;
for (char ch : str.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
    if (ch == 'x') {
        x++;
    } else if (ch == 'o') {
        o++;
    }
}
return o == x;
```

Comment: `toLowerCase()` *and* `toCharArray()`? Are we *made* of money?

Comment: @AndyTurner I could have written `return IntStream.range(0, str.length()).filter(i -> str.charAt(i) == 'X' || str.charAt(i) == 'x').count() == IntStream.range(0, str.length()).filter(i -> str.charAt(i) == 'Y' || str.charAt(i) == 'y').count();`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do any splitting. Aside from the fact it's not correct (try `oooxxx`, for example, or `OOOxxx`), it's rather inefficient, because it requires creating new objects. You don't need to do this.

Just iterate a character at a time, checking what the current character is, and increment/decrement a counter:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
  switch (str.charAt(i)) {
    case 'o': case 'O':
      count++;
      break;
    case 'x': case 'X':
      count--;
      break;
  }
}
return count == 0;
```

Prefer using an indexed loop and `charAt` rather than iterating `toCharArray()`, because the latter creates a new char array containing the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string) post. You could do something like

`return StringUtils.countMatches(str, "x") == StringUtils.countMatches(str, "o")`.

Why invent the wheel twice? Let me know if that helps you. I did not try the code, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually many different ways to accomplish thhis:

- [Count Occurrences of a Char in a String](https://www.baeldung.com/java-count-chars)

  - Imperative Approach
  - Using Recursion
  - Using Regular Expressions
  - Using Java 8 Features
  - Using 3rd party libraries (notably Apache Commons or Spring Framework)

This example is something I might try (at least as a first cut, before "optimizing"):

```
public static boolean isSameXOCount (String str) {
  int ctX = 0, ctO = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if (c == 'X' || c == 'x')
      ctX++;
    else if (c == 'O' || c == 'o')
      ctO++;
  }
  return ctX == ct);
}
```