# How to count comma in a String java

Tags: java

I have a String, which contains a lot of commas.

**I want to count all the commas in the String but I don't know how**.

I'm using `(split(",")-1)`

But the problem is that if I input a String like this: `One,Two,Three,Four,,,`

Then it returns only 3 while I want it to be 6.

I think it is because `split(",")` returns a String[] that does not include null or empty values.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I count the number of occurrences of a char in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

One straightforward way would be to just compare the length of the input against the input with all commas removed:

```java
String input = "One,Two,Three,Four,,,";
int numCommas = input.length() - input.replace(",", "").length();
System.out.println(numCommas);  // prints 6
```